# Why does this code have different outputs if pointers are incremented differently c++

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int num=10;
  int *ptr=NULL;
  ptr=&num;
  num=(*ptr)++; //it should increase to 11
  num=(*ptr)++; //it should increase to 12 but im getting 10
                //if i dont initialize num and just use (*ptr)++ it gives me 11
  cout<<num<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know why is this happening and why am I getting 10 as output.

Comment: Yet another evidence of why it is not good to change a value twice in a single expression.  :-)

Comment: Just a note that, **before C++17**, `num=(*ptr)++;` exhibits undefined behaviour. Compilers will likely not spot it but, replacing with `num = num++` will generate *warning : multiple unsequenced modifications to 'num' [-Wunsequenced]* with clang-cl (using the C++14 Standard).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(*ptr)++` increases `num` to 11 but returns its previous value (10), because the `++` is postfix.

So with `num = (*ptr)++`, you are temporarily increasing `num` to 11, but then (re)assigning it with 10.

Comment: New to coding and don't know the term post fix i'll search it up thanks for reply

Answer (score 1):

> why is this happening

Because you are using **post-increment operator** instead of **pre-increment operator**.

Replace `(*ptr)++` with:

```
num = ++(*ptr);//uses pre-increment operator
```

And you will get 12 as output at the end of the program which can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/xFaoUpWAy).

##### Alternative solution

You can also just write `(*ptr)++;` without doing assignment to `num`. So in this case code would look like:

```
int main() {
  int num=10;
  int *ptr=NULL;
  ptr=&num;
  (*ptr)++; //no need for assignment to num
  (*ptr)++; //no need for assignment to num
                
  cout<<num<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just `(*ptr)++;` for each statement.

Comment: im rather new and didn't knew that post and pre increment or decrement can affect a code like this thanks for reply tho

Comment: @AliMardan You're welcome. Also note that as Adrian suggested you can also use `(*ptr)++;` **without assigning** to `num`. I have added this at the end of my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by assigning to num. ++ operator returns old value and then increments. However, then the old value is assigned to num.